# Add dynamic node to xml file in php

Tags: php, xml, dynamic

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 
http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
   <url>
     <loc>
        some url here
     </loc>
     <lastmod>2019-07-01T21:33:53-07:00</lastmod>
     <priority>0.80</priority>
   </url>
```

Above one is my old xml data, I want add a new "child url" to it in php. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two APIs in PHP for that, DOM and XMLWriter. DOM is the most flexible to manipulate an existing XML document. However it need to load it into memory. If your sitemap is small enough you can just load the current XML and append new `{http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9}url` nodes.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
   <url>
     <loc>http://www.example.com/some_page.html</loc>
     <lastmod>2019-07-01T21:33:53-07:00</lastmod>
     <priority>0.80</priority>
   </url>
</urlset>
XML;

const XMLNS_SITEMAP = 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9';
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$document->loadXML($xml);
$urlNode = $document->documentElement->appendChild(
    $document->createElementNS(XMLNS_SITEMAP, 'url')
);
$urlNode->appendChild(
    $document->createElementNS(XMLNS_SITEMAP, 'loc')
)->textContent = 'http://www.example.com/another_page.htm';
$urlNode->appendChild(
    $document->createElementNS(XMLNS_SITEMAP, 'lastmod')
)->textContent = date(DATE_ATOM);
$urlNode->appendChild(
    $document->createElementNS(XMLNS_SITEMAP, 'priority')
)->textContent = '0.5';

$document->formatOutput = true;
echo $document->saveXML();
```

If the sitemap is to large you will need to use XMLReader to read the XML in parts and XMLWriter to write it.